Visual Studio Code - Typing /// does not autogenerate "summary"
On a new computer so I had to fresh install everything. In the past, when I typed "///" before a method, VS code would autogenerate a "summary" block that I could fill in with parameters, return types, exceptions, etc. Now, when I type ///, nothing happens. Language is C#, though I feel like that might not matter for this problem.
I've looked online everywhere for anyone else with the same issue and couldn't find a thing. Any ideas?

Visual Studio automatically inserts the  and  tags and positions your cursor within these tags after you type the /// delimiter in the code editor. You can turn this feature on or off in the Options dialog box  (From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/)

@Luuk: this question relates to Visual Studio Code, not Visual Studio.
